# Dimensions must be equal, but are 1 and 2 for 'Conv2D' (op: 'Conv2D') with input shapes: [2,2,2,1], [1,1,2,1]

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am trying to learn Conv2d by this code.

Based on conv2d doc:

shape of input = [batch, in_height, in_width, in_channels]

shape of filter = [filter_height, filter_width, in_channels, out_channels]

When I try to run it , it sends me the wrong message.

```
#-*-coding:utf-8-*-

import tensorflow as tf

input_batch = tf.constant([
    [
        [[0.0], [1.0]],
        [[2.0], [3.0]]
    ],
    [
        [[2.0], [4.0]],
        [[6.0], [8.0]]
    ]
])

kernel = tf.constant([
    [
        [[1.0], [2.0]],
    ]
])

conv2d = tf.nn.conv2d(input_batch, kernel, strides=[1, 1, 1, 1],padding='SAME')

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(conv2d)
```

The wrong message:

```
ValueError: Dimensions must be equal, but are 1 and 2 for 'Conv2D' (op: 'Conv2D') with input shapes: [2,2,2,1], [1,1,2,1].
```